# How to compare variance of two groups (one normal distribution, one non-normal distribution) with different sample sizes?

Tags: r, variance

I have 79 individuals. I have two categories of individuals (1 and 2). I have a measure of speed for each individual. Category 1 has 54 individuals and has a non-normal distribution of speeds, category 2 has 25 individuals and has a normal distribution of speeds.

Here is representative data...

```
group_data <- structure(list(speed = c(17.09, 12.29, 12.66, 13.9, 27.6, 14.4, 9.075, 38.9, 7.08, 13.31, 
                                       21.2, 21.5, 4.9, 14.8, 20.36, 14.26, 14.585, 22.315, 21.2, 17.82, 
                                       12.92, 2.7, 23.9, 6.5, 8.2, 4.2, 4.8, 4.905, 3.17, 12.5, 6.17, 
                                       20.6, 2.425, 20.6, 30.6, 22.24, 2.71, 2.87, 4.76, 8.89, 10.89, 
                                       22.16, 27.48, 29, 30.89, 27.28, 30.83, 14.4, 19.15, 1, 3.6, 3.8, 
                                       3.7, 24.0, 8.7, 9.9, 10.9, 16.4, 17.59, 17.99, 18.1, 18.48, 19.3, 20, 
                                       20, 20.79, 20.89, 21.01, 21.1, 22.93, 23.65, 24.25, 24.46, 25.15, 
                                       28.1, 29.2, 32.3, 32.7, 17.8), 
                             group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                       1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                       2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)), 
                            .Names = c("speed", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1:79))
```

Here is what the data look like...

```
library(ggplot2)

figure <- ggplot(data, aes(x=category, y=speed, fill = category)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color = "black", outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.25, alpha=0.65, size = 4) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=4) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  ylab("Speed") +
  xlab("Category") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 3)))

figure
```

[image]

As you can see it appears that category 1 has greater variance than category 2. However, couldn't this be simply a result of having roughly double the number of individuals in category 1 than in category 2? **What is an appropriate test to see if the variances of these two categories truly are different, taking account the difference in the number of individuals per category and in the differences in normality vs. non-normality?** I have been trying to read about bootstrapping or permutation techniques that will subsample the larger category to make it a comparable size to the small category, but I have been unable to find what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a permutation test for a valid comparison of the variances of your two groups.

Begin by capturing the speed data from your Question and
finding the variances of the two groups.

```
speed = c(17.09, 12.29, 12.66, 13.9, 27.6, 14.4, 9.075, 38.9, 7.08, 13.31, 
       21.2, 21.5, 4.9, 14.8, 20.36, 14.26, 14.585, 22.315, 21.2, 17.82, 
       12.92, 2.7, 23.9, 6.5, 8.2, 4.2, 4.8, 4.905, 3.17, 12.5, 6.17, 
       20.6, 2.425, 20.6, 30.6, 22.24, 2.71, 2.87, 4.76, 8.89, 10.89, 
       22.16, 27.48, 29, 30.89, 27.28, 30.83, 14.4, 19.15, 1, 3.6, 3.8, 
       3.7, 24.0, 8.7, 9.9, 10.9, 16.4, 17.59, 17.99, 18.1, 18.48, 19.3, 20, 
       20, 20.79, 20.89, 21.01, 21.1, 22.93, 23.65, 24.25, 24.46, 25.15, 
       28.1, 29.2, 32.3, 32.7, 17.8) 
group=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
table(group)
 group
 1  2 
54 25 
v1 = var(speed[group==1]);  v1
[1] 89.90077
v2 = var(speed[group==2]);  v2
[1] 36.69211
rat.obs = v1/v2;  rat.obs
[1] 2.450139
boxplot(speed~group, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

To test $H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_1^2 = 1$ against
$H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_1^2 > 1,$ using an F test,
would not be appropriate because the samples are not
both normal. (F tests are sensitive to departures from
normality.) Even so, we show results of the F-test below.

```
var.test(speed~group, alt="g")

        F test to compare two variances

data:  speed by group
F = 2.4501, num df = 53, denom df = 24, p-value = 0.0094
alternative hypothesis: 
  true ratio of variances is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.320303      Inf
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          2.450139
```

Notice that the Shaprio-Wilk normality test for Group 1 strongly rejects normality.

```
shapiro.test(speed[group==1])$p.val
[1] 0.01507562
```

So, we have reason to doubt that the F-statistic
$F = S_1^2/S_2^2$ has the expected F distribution.
However, it does seem reasonable use the ratio of variances
as a metric for comparing the two group variances.
So we proceed to find the approximate permutation distribution
of this ratio.

We do this by repeatedly permuting the $54+25=79$ speeds into two groups of 54 and 25, respectively, and finding the
variance ratio of the two 'groups' after each permutation. Many such ratios give us a good idea of the permutation
distribution of the F-statistic.

However, as @Glen_b has commented, we need to use data
that are 'exchangeable` under the null hypothesis
$H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 = 1.$ So, we use deviations $d_{ji}$ from group means instead of speeds $x_{ji},$
as follows: $d_{ji} = x_{ji} -\bar x_j, j = 1,2.$ Group
variances are unchanged.

```
s1 = speed[group==1]; d1 = s1-mean(s1);  v1 = var(d1)
s2 = speed[group==2]; d2 = s2-mean(s2);  v2 = var(d2)
rat.obs = v1/v2; rat.obs
[1] 2.450139  # same as F-statistic above.
```

In the R code below, we use `sample(group)` to scramble
the observations at each iteration, and (somewhat wastefully of running time)
we use `var.test` to find the F-ratio for each iteration.

With P-value $0.00314< 0.005 = 0.5\%$ the one-sided
permutation test results in rejection of $H_0.$

```
set.seed(2022)
rat.prm = replicate(10^5,
                 var.test(d~sample(group))$stat)
mean(rat.prm >= rat.obs)
[1] 0.00314   # P-value of one-sided permutation test
```

The histogram below shows the approximate permutation
distribution, along with the observed value of the variance ratio for your original, unscrambled groups (dotted red line).

```
hdr = "Permutation Dist'n of Ratio of Variances"
hist(rat.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v = rat.obs, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely helpful response! Just one question... where does the 0.002 value for assessing significance come from? Is that, just like the normal 0.05, simply the arbitrary accepted value for acceptance in this type of test?

Comment: In an application, you have a choice to test at a specific level: 5%, 2%, 1%, 0.1%, etc. Or you can pretend to be a software program and report the P-value. If the P-value is 0.00165<0.002=0.2%, you can claim significance at the 0.2% level. There is controversy whether the 5% significance level ought to be the 'standard' for publication. Also, about how to handle reporting P-values. Or whether to report them at all.

Comment: Bruce, doesn't your use of a permutation test rely on these values being exchangeable under H0? When the variances are the same but the means are not assumed to be the same under H0, don't think you have exchangeability unless you add an assumption (e.g. that when the variances are the same whole distribution, including the means, will also be the same), one that might not be tenable in this case. [Consider what happens with the test when your data have the same variance but very different means; how does the the type I error rate of the test look?]

Comment: @Glen_b.  Thans for the correction note. Used deviations from group means to preserve group variances and yet get exchangeable data.

Comment: You're permuting residuals? You'd no longer have an exact distribution-free test, wouldn't you? (Well, I suppose asymptotically it should be fine, so it's probably okay in an approximate sense, more or less like a bootstrap test would be)

Comment: If the sample sizes were the same, I think it works, but otherwise I think the small-sample distribution is different. This is not going to be a practical issue at these sample sizes, though.